# Why is my bootstrap thumbnail INSIDE my Jumbotron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have successfully created a jumbotron on a page of mine, and I want to have a few thumbnails and things BELOW the jumbotron, outside of it. Yet, even with a separate  section, the thumbnail somehow ends up inside the jumbotron, extending it therefore annoying me :P Anyway to fix this and make the jumbotron and thumbnail separate?

My HTML

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
      <h1><font color="#0095f0" face="">Blog!</font></h1>
      <p><font color="#0095f0"><strong>Blah blah blah ect :P</strong></font></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">View Blogs!</a></p>
    </div>
    </body>

    <body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/question-mark_318-52837.jpg" alt="Annas Blog">
             <div class="caption">
            <h3><font face="Calibri"><strong>The Blog!</strong></font></h3>
            <p><small>View Blog! That's why you're here anyway... right?</small></p>
            <p><a href="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/question-mark_318-52837.jpg" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Blogs!</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And My CSS

```
        .jumbotron {
            margin: 15px 0 30px 0;
            background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/question-mark_318-52837.jpg");
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-position: 30% 90%;
        }

        .row {
            margin: 0 5px;
        }
```

Yet it shows up like this? please view link...

[image: screen capture]

Please help me fix this :)

Comment: Its hard to tell without the whole tag. Maybe there is a problem with closing those tags. Start by putting them in just one `<body></body>`

Comment: The structure of your HTML is all messed up: there are some random <body> tags, the jumbotron <div> has no closing </div>, and who knows what else is wrong there. Clean up your mess and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra body tag and close jumbotron div properly

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
      <h1><font color="#0095f0" face="">Blog!</font></h1>
      <p><font color="#0095f0"><strong>Blah blah blah ect :P</strong></font></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">View Blogs!</a></p>
    </div>
</div>  // Close it here
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/question-mark_318-52837.jpg" alt="Annas Blog">
             <div class="caption">
            <h3><font face="Calibri"><strong>The Blog!</strong></font></h3>
            <p><small>View Blog! That's why you're here anyway... right?</small></p>
            <p><a href="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/question-mark_318-52837.jpg" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Blogs!</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following properties from your .jumbotron CSS:

```
background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/question-mark_318-52837.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 30% 90%;
```

So it should look like this:

```
    .jumbotron {
        margin: 15px 0 30px 0;
    }
```